# How to change the color of overview for my flutter application

Tags: android, flutter

Now I want to change the color of the bottom **OverView** (which has balck color initially and has three buttons home, back..) and I  want the color from black to white. But I don't want to remove the SafeArea widget.

So I have an application that looks like this.
[image: Screenshot]

Here I have mentioned the code of my main.dart file. I have not done anything for Overview color but this code will give an understanding of what is happing.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:Healthwise/pages/listPage.dart';
import 'package:Healthwise/pages/resultPage.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:Healthwise/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';

List<CameraDescription>? cameras;
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          // We have removed the appbar
          // appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          //   systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          //       statusBarColor: Colors.white,
          //       statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light),
          // ),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
            cursorColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 126, 153),
            selectionColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 126, 153),
            selectionHandleColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 126, 153),
          ),
        ),
        home: Home());
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:Healthwise/pages/listPage.dart';
import 'package:Healthwise/pages/resultPage.dart';
import 'package:Healthwise/helpers/user.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:Healthwise/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import '../helpers/frontEnd.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isWorking = false;
  String result = '';

  CameraController? cameraController;
  CameraImage? imgCamera;

  initCamera() {
    cameraController = CameraController(cameras![0], ResolutionPreset.max);
    cameraController!.initialize().then((value) {
      if (!mounted) {
        print("Camera Not Mounted");
        return;
      } else {
        setState(() {
          cameraController!.startImageStream((imageFromStream) {
            if (!isWorking) {
              isWorking = true;
              imgCamera = imageFromStream;
              runModelOnStreamFrames();
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  loadModel() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: 'assets/model_unquant.tflite',
      labels: 'assets/labels.txt',
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadModel();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    await Tflite.close();
    await cameraController?.dispose();
  }

  runModelOnStreamFrames() async {
    var racognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
      bytesList: imgCamera!.planes.map((plane) {
        return plane.bytes;
      }).toList(),
      imageHeight: imgCamera!.height,
      imageWidth: imgCamera!.width,
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
      rotation: 90,
      numResults: 1,
      threshold: 0.1,
      asynch: true,
    );

    racognitions!.forEach((response) {
      var res = response['confidence'] as double;

      if (res > 0.95) {
        result = response['label'];
        //  +
        //     ' ' +
        //     (response['confidence'] as double).toStringAsFixed(2);
      }
    });
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        result;
      });
    }

    isWorking = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
      child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          floatingActionButton: imgCamera == null
              ? CameraOpeningButton()
              : CloseCameraAndSearch(cameraController),
          // appBar:
          //     AppBar(backgroundColor: primary_color, title: application_name),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(children: [
              Container(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/SVG/MainBackground.png"),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                // height: 560,
                child: Container(
                    height: 650,
                    width: 360,
                    child: imgCamera == null
                        ? Column(
                            children: [
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              SearchBar(),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              Center(
                                  child: Container(
                                height: 500,
                                width: 340,
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Color(0xFFffffff),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      blurRadius: 2.0, // soften the shadow
                                      spreadRadius: 2.0, //extend the shadow
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      height: 50,
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 126, 153),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Banana",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                255, 255, 255, 255),
                                            fontSize: 25,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Image.network(
                                              'https://images.everydayhealth.com/images/diet-nutrition/all-about-bananas-nutrition-facts-health-benefits-recipes-and-more-rm-722x406.jpg?w=1110'),
                                          Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                vertical: 30, horizontal: 30),
                                            child: Text(
                                              '"If you feel recurrent soreness of muscles after a workout, you may lack magnesium in your body. A magnesium-rich banana may help with muscle contraction and relaxation that increase lean muscle mass."',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                    255, 80, 80, 80),
                                                fontSize: 20,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        : AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: cameraController!.value.aspectRatio,
                            child: CameraPreview(cameraController!),
                          )),
              ),
            ]),
          )

          //   body: Container(
          //     decoration: BoxDecoration(),
          //     child: Column(children: [
          //       Stack(
          //         children: [
          //           Center(
          //             child: Container(
          //               margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
          //               height: 220,
          //               width: 320,
          //               child: Container(),
          //             ),
          //           ),
          //           Center(
          //             child: TextButton(
          //               onPressed: () {
          //                 initCamera();
          //               },
          //               child: Container(
          //                   margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
          //                   height: 550,
          //                   width: 360,
          //                   child: imgCamera == null
          //                       ? Container(
          //                           height: 550,
          //                           width: 360,
          //                           child: Icon(
          //                             Icons.photo_camera_front,
          //                             color: Colors.pink,
          //                             size: 60,
          //                           ),
          //                         )
          //                       : AspectRatio(
          //                           aspectRatio:
          //                               cameraController!.value.aspectRatio,
          //                           child: CameraPreview(cameraController!),
          //                         )),
          //             ),
          //           )
          //         ],
          //       ),
          //       Center(
          //         child: Container(
          //           color: primary_color,
          //           margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
          //           child: SingleChildScrollView(
          //               // controller: controller,
          //               child: Text(
          //             result,
          //             style: const TextStyle(
          //                 backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          //                 fontSize: 10.0,
          //                 color: Colors.white),
          //             textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          //           )),
          //         ),
          //       ),
          //       ElevatedButton(
          //           onPressed: () async {
          //             if (result != '') {
          //               await cameraController?.stopImageStream();
          //               await cameraController?.pausePreview();
          //               itemName = result.toString();
          //               print("--------------------------------------------");
          //               print(itemName);
          //               Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          //                   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultPage()));
          //             }
          //           },
          //           child: Container(
          //             child: Text("Next"),
          //             color: Colors.blue,
          //           ))
          //     ]),
          //   ),
          ),
    );
  }

  Row CloseCameraAndSearch(CameraController? cameraController) =>
      Row(children: [
//Camera Close
        TextButton(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.pink),
          onPressed: () async {
            await cameraController?.stopImageStream();
            await cameraController?.pausePreview();
            imgCamera = null;
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/SVG/CloseCamera.png'),
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
          ),
        ),

//Result
        Spacer(),

        Container(
          color: primary_color,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              // controller: controller,
              child: Text(
            result,
            style: const TextStyle(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 10.0,
                color: Colors.white),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          )),
        ),

//Camera Close Next Page
        Spacer(),
        TextButton(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.pink),
          onPressed: () async {
            if (result != '') {
              await cameraController?.stopImageStream();
              await cameraController?.pausePreview();
              itemName = result.toString();
              print(itemName);
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultPage()));
            }
          },
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/SVG/SearchFruitButton.png'),
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
          ),
        )
      ]);

  // Camera Open

  TextButton CameraOpeningButton() {
    return TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.pink),
      onPressed: () {
        initCamera();
      },
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage('assets/SVG/CameraButton.png'),
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
      ),
    );
  }

//SearchBar
  Container SearchBar() {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 340,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 10, 0),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        //
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey,
            blurRadius: 2.0, // soften the shadow
            spreadRadius: 2.0, //extend the shadow
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 40,
            width: 240,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Search Pomegranate'),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          TextButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd),
            onPressed: () => {result},
            child: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 126, 153),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a custom systemNavigationBar color

```
var mySystemTheme= SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
 .copyWith(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.green);

SystemChrome.setSystemUiOverlayStyle(mySystemTheme);
```